# Understand how the TLB (Translation Lookaside buffer) works and interacts with pagetable and addresses

Tags: caching

So I am trying to understand this TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer). But I am having a hard time grasping it.

in context of having two streams of addresses, tlb and pagetable.

I don't understand the association of the TLB to the streamed addresses/tags and page tables.

```
a.  4669, 2227, 13916, 34587, 48870, 12608, 49225
b.  12948, 49419, 46814, 13975, 40004, 12707
```

```
TLB
Valid   Tag Physical Page Number
1   11  12
1   7   4
1   3   6
0   4   9
```

```
Page Table
Valid   Physical Page or in Disk
1   5
0   Disk
0   Disk
1   6
1   9
1   11
0   Disk
1   4
0   Disk
0   Disk
1   3
1   12
```

How does the TLB work with the pagetable and addresses? The homework question given is:

Given the address stream in the table, and the initial TLB and page table states shown above, show the final state of the system also list for each reference if it is a hit in the TLB, a hit in the page table or a page fault.

But I think first i just need to know how does the TLB work with these other elements and how to determine things. How do I even start to answer this question?

Comment: for homework question you want to read this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Although I did list the question I am trying to answer, the primary question is more information on the TLB in general and understanding it. To which i can then start to answer the question.

Comment: stream of addresses is sequence of addresses that needs to be accessed by looking at tlb then page table. Just run through them and make notes of the state of the tlb and page table. There's a page for tlb: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer